# Trying to add a "res" folder as a class folder?

Tags: eclipse, macos

I am trying to add a resource folder on Eclipse Mars(mac) by adding it from the project properties. It works on my windows pc but it creates a package on my mac... Does anyone know why?

**Steps I take:**
Create folder in Project Explorer > Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries > Add Class Folder and then I select "res" but it tries to put it in a package.

[image: This is the end result of the steps I took.]

Comment: Please tell us exactly what steps you are using to create the folder.

Comment: Create folder in **Project Explorer** > **Project** > **Properties** > **Java Build Path** > **Libraries** > **Add Class Folder** and then I select "res" but it tries to put it in a package.

Comment: @greg-449 See above^

Comment: But what you are adding is not a Class Folder. Why not just right click on the project and choose New > Folder.

Comment: It needs to be referenced otherwise it will not work though. @greg-449